# what does this do

Tags: php

$top += $i ? 12 : 0;

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If `$i` is

- set
- and not `false`
- and not `null`

increment `$top` by twelve; otherwise, by zero, implicitly turning `$top` (**not** `$i`) into a numeric variable if it isn't one already.

Comment: In addition, if `$i` is not set, it raises a warning.

Comment: @R.B good point. To avoid the warning, `(isset($i) and ($i))` should be used instead of `$i`.

Comment: When $i is turned to a numeric variable, does it get the value 0?

What is it about php that causes $i to be implicitly turned into a numeric var? And why is it implicitly changed to be numeric var, as opposed to a boolean (since the ternary operator might suggest a boolean codition)?

Comment: I still don't see why php expects $i to be an integer... Since the ternary operator is supposed to be similar to:
`if ($a) { return $b; } else { return $c; }`


Then why in the world does it "need" $i to be an int?

Comment: @Eddified arrrrrgh, now I see. `$i` is never expected to be an integer and will never be turned into one. *`$top`* will get turned into an integer through the `+0` operation. I put the wrong variable name into the text. Mea culpa, sorry sorry. Corrected and removed my comment.

Answer (score 11):

If `$i` has a value set (not empty/null meaning condition resolves to true), then 12 is added to `$top` and `0` otherwise.

It is basically shorthand of:

```
if ($i)
{
  $top += 12;
}
else
{
  $top += 0;
}
```

**[This is known as Ternary operator.](http://www.addedbytes.com/code/ternary-conditionals/)**

Answer (score 4):

Shorthand for:

```
if ($i) {
  $top += 12;
}
```

Comment: you are missing `else` there.

Comment: @Sarfraz is right: If `$i` is not numeric before the operation, the `+0` would make an implicit conversion, so it's not 100% identical (even though in practice, it's probably not relevant as `$i` will probably be numeric). Good answer either way.

Answer (score 2):

If $i is true (e.g., not zero or an empty string), 12 is added to $top. Otherwise, nothing is added to $top.

This is equivalent to

```
if($i)
    $top = top + 12;
```

Answer (score 1):

Increase value of `$top` by `12` if `$i` has true boolean value (ie. `$i = 1`, `$i = true` etc.) or by `0` if not.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php

[Ternary Operaotr](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation

Answer (score 0):

The $i ? 12 : 0 is a "shorthand" if statement. In this case, $i is evaluated as an expression.  If the expression evaluates to true, then the value 12 is used as the r-value in the addition-assignment expression.  If $i evaluates to false, then 0 is used as the r-value.